# JavaScript hybrid app crashlytics Log

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, google-fabric

I am developing iOS/Android Hybrid App. I want to leave a Crashlytics Log using Fabric in my app. I found out that when I try to throw an exception by linking the example project in android studio, it will be forcibly terminated. If I keep the log and use try ~ catch, I know that the log will be left after reloading the app. However, in a javascipt-based hybrid app, i'm use crashlytics log exception, and throwing an exception will not cause the log to be logged. Interlocking is perfect. If I rerun the app, it not be taken logged. Any help?

This is my code

```
1. $('#testCrash').click(function(){ 
throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash"); });  
2.$('#testCrash').click(function(){ 
       try{ 
        throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");              }catch(RuntimeException e){ 
crashlytics.logexception(e); } });
```

It’s not taken logged..

Comment: Give any code please...

Comment: Please edit your code in the question

Comment: I got it. Im edit my question